# Ensuring a transactional update succeeds with ndb.ComputedProperty non-ancestor query

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a transactional function that updates a Model entity as follows

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def do_something(some_key):
   some_entity = some_key.get()
   some_entity.some_property = "New value"
   some_entity.put()

class TheModel(ndb.Model):
    some_property = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()

    @ndb.ComputedProperty
    def md5(self):
        try:
            bi = blobstore.BlobInfo(self.blob_key)
            if bi:
                return bi.md5_hash
            return None
         except:
             logging.error(sys.exc_info())
```

When I run `do_something` the put fails - and from testing I can see that this is due to the transactional nature of the function. I gather that the blobstore query / get by key is causing the failure.

Is there an established way to ensure ComputedProperties work (where the computation involves non-ancestor queries) with models that are included in transactional functions?

Edit 1:
I'm catching the exception with `sys.exc_info()` and it returns

`(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'Key' object has no attribute 'reference'",), <traceback object at 0xf613c968>)`

Edit 2:
The exception does not occur if I remove the decorator.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback you're getting for the failure?

Comment: I get the feeling that some confusion may be leading your thoughts in the wrong direction: you have no query in your example, get by key is just a lookup, not a query and, in general, queries (ancestor or not) are applicable to the datastore, not to the blobstore (different things).

Comment: Dan - thanks for responding. As per the edit - I've found that the exception does not occur if I remove the decorator for the same entity. The presence of the decorator is what determines whether the `put()` succeeds or fails (in the absence of the `try`/`except`).

Comment: Please incorporate the full traceback, just the error is not relevant as it's not in the code you show (there is no `.reference` in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ndb has two handy approaches to overcome this. There is the [`ndb.in_transaction`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/functions#in_transaction) approach which returns `True` if the operation is part of a transaction (so I can run or not run the lookup code). The second approach, which I've ended up using is to use the [`@ndb.non_transactional`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/functions#non_transactional) decorator as shown below which from the docs is a

> Decorator to ensure that a function runs outside a transaction.

```
class TheModel(ndb.Model):
    some_property = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()

    @ndb.ComputedProperty
    @ndb.non_transactional
    def md5(self):
        try:
            bi = blobstore.BlobInfo(self.blob_key)
            if bi:
                return bi.md5_hash
            return None
         except:
             logging.error(sys.exc_info())
```